# How to create the special toast and swipe down on lock screen like Skype in win8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, skype, lockscreen

In win8.1, we can swipe down on lock screen to open camera.
And also can answer a Skype call from the lock screen.

http://webwereld.nl/development/79224-skype-omzeilt-lockscreen-windows-8-1---update
http://www.stckwt.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=137

I want to create a windows store App like Skype.
When someone call, it will show a special toast : user can also choose how to respond – answer call or decline.
If user choose answer call in lock screen, it will auto swipe down the screen and begin answer call.

But I have no idea.

Does anyone have similar experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alarm Toast Notification sample shows how to do this for an application that is the Alarm application for the machine:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Alarm-toast-notifications-fe81fc74

If your application is a VOIP application then you can modify the toast XML String in that sample to be the following:

```
                string toastXmlString =
                "<toast duration=\"long\">\n" +
                    "<visual>\n" +
                        "<binding template=\"ToastText02\">\n" +
                            "<text id=\"1\">Alarms Notifications SDK Sample App</text>\n" +
                            "<text id=\"2\">" + alarmName + "</text>\n" +
                        "</binding>\n" +
                    "</visual>\n" +
                    "<commands scenario=\"incomingCall\">\n" +
                        "<command id=\"voice\"/>\n" +
                        "<command id=\"video\"/>\n" +
                        "<command id=\"decline\"/>\n" +
                    "</commands>\n" +
                    "<audio src=\"ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Looping.Alarm2\" loop=\"true\" />\n" +
                "</toast>\n";
```

Note that this will only work if you have an application that can accept incoming calls.

Also the following blog goes over this as well:
http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2013/09/27/windows-8-1-preview-and-alarm-call-applications.aspx